# How to make SOAP request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, soap, soap-client

[image]

This request requires Basic Auth: user and password.

[image]

Headers with two fields.

[image]

and xml body.

This API is tested working in Postman.
But I am not sure how to make this work in Laravel, I only work with JSON before.

Any suggestion how can I get started? or any package I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use http post

```
 $http=Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type'=>'application/xml',
            'SOAPAction'=>'balance'
        ])->post(url,$xmlBodyContent);
    
    
    
        return response($http->body())
            ->withHeaders([
                'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'
            ]);
```

Another way is to use `withBody` method

```
$http=Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type'=>'application/xml',
            'SOAPAction'=>'balance'
        ])->withBody($xmlBodyContent,"text/xml")->post(url);
```

for xml doc notation
Ref:https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

To generate array to xml,use [array-to-xml](https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml)

Comment: As an addition to this answer I think you should check out Spatie's array to xml package, makes a world of difference IMO
https://github.com/spatie/array-to-xml

Comment: Works great. https://sabre.io/xml/ to write is also a great option to write XML's.

Comment: $http=Http::withHeaders([
            'Content-Type'=>'application/xml',
            'SOAPAction'=>'balance'
        ])->withBody($xmlBodyContent,"text/xml")->post(url);

This one is worked for me.